# what to change in my php script for the cron job to work

Tags: php, cron

Ok I have been looking into cron jobs for hours, checked every post here, looked in google but I just do not understand how it works.

I have set up a cron job using my path `1 * * * * /home/myuser/domains/mysite/public_html/live.php` I have also tried `/home/myuser/public_html/live.php`
Nothing seems to be working.

Do I have to add something in the php file (`live.php`)? That is the code that has to be executed. The code itself works.

I know you will all think that I am lazy but I really can't figure this out.

Comment: How do you run it from the command line right now?

Comment: You need to call PHP and pass the path as a parameter. E.x. `/usr/bin/php /home/myuser/domains/mysite/public_html/live.php`

Comment: Where do I place that command? I really have no clue :p

Comment: A cron job runs on the server, as if you were sitting at a terminal and typing commands. It runs at a certain time. If you are setting up a cron job, that means you know what you want to run from the command line (or shell script).

If you aren't sure what that is, maybe the cron job is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I need a cron job, but I just need to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.php` is regular script file which, as any other scripting languages like i.e. perl requires interpreter to run. So if you want to run your script from command line you have either call interpreter and give it your script file as argument, like:

```
$ /usr/bin/php myscript.php
```

And that's it - it should run.

Or (if working using linux/bsd) add **as very first line of your PHP script file**:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

which tells shell, where to look for interpreter for this script file. Please ensure your PHP is in `/usr/bin` folder as this may vary depending on the distro. You can check this using `which`, like this:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

if path is right, you yet need to set executable bit on script file so you'd be able to try to "launch it":

```
chmod a+x myscript.php
```

This will make it behave as any other app, so you'd be able to launch it this way:

```
/full/path/to/myscript.php
```

or from current folder:

```
./myscript.php
```

And that's it for that approach. It should run.

So your crontab line would look (depending on the choosen approach):

```
1 * * * * /full/path/to/myscript.php
```

or

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /full/path/to/myscript.php
```

And you should rather use "0" not "1", as 1st minute in hour is zero, i.e.:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /full/path/to/myscript.php
```

**EDIT**

Please note cron **working directory** is user's home directory. So you need to put that into consideration, which usually means using absolute pathes. Alternatively you'd prepend your call with `cd <script working path> && /usr/bin/php -q /full/....`

Comment: for the first approach, where do I place the "$ /usr/bin/php myscript.php" ?

Comment: This is not a script. It means that you should open a console/terminal as you (`$` usually means user, while `#` superuser) and execute command `/usr/bin/php myscript.php` and see the result

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still in the dark..
What do I need to add in my phpscript that I uploaded in the "public_html" folder.
And what do I need to type as the command in the cron job menu of my linux server?

Comment: you need at least `cron`/`crontab` access (or any equivalent) or shell (ssh) access to remote machine. If the former - check user manual, if the latter, and you got cron/-ish daemon, then you do `crontab -e` to open texteditor, add this `0 * * ....` line there. write and quit - if you put correct pathes it shall work.

Comment: You are still kind of speaking Chinese to me :p

Comment: Then, sorry, you should hire someone - this is pretty much elementary what I talk about. Maybe you should not administer any server but focus on your job?

Comment: I will just give it another whirl! Thank you for all your effort :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
1 * * * * php /home/myuser/domains/mysite/public_html/live.php
```

Comment: Do I just have to paste that randomly in my script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your script executable with chmod on the command line.
Furthermore you need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// here comes your code
?>
```

This is required to tell the command line how to execute the file. 
Note: this will only work if your php binary is located in /usr/bin/php

Comment: "You need to make your script executable with chmod on the command line." how do I do this?

Comment: @eX0du5: do not use trailing `?>` unless you know you need it. If not used, scripts ends with file end

Comment: I know, I just wanted to show that a standard php content should follow. for my class definitions for example I never have a closing ?>

And regarding chmod: http://linuxwiki.de/chmod